# Smartface.io webview access gallery not working (android)

Tags: android, webview, gallery, smartface.io

I tried inside `WebView` upload a file (image). When click upload button nothing happen on android device. But iOS device open gallery and I can upload photo in `WebView`.

I set android permisions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


function mainpage_buttonMainAdd_OnTouch(e){
Pages.mainpage.reset()
Pages.mainpage.loadingMain.visible=true;
var webviewMain = new SMF.UI.WebView({
top: "0%",
left: "0%",
width:"100%",
height:"87%",
openLinkInside:"true",
URL: "AAAAAAAAA"
});
Pages.mainpage.add(webviewMain);
}
```

And I can access camera and gallery in image button.
But can I access gallery in `WebView`?

Comment: I am facing same issue. did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to share the link which you try to make upload ?

WebView uses device' native browser inside it. I guess maybe there is a limitation about it.